# what is domain of $f(x)=(-1)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What exactly is the domain of the $$f(x)=(-1)^x$$

Because if $x=\pm0.5$ or $x=\pm0.25$ etc we get imaginary numbers.

But if we take $x=\pm\frac{1}{3}$ we get a real number, so how to define its domain?

Do we restrict it to only integers?

Comment: You *could* define the function for all rationals that can be represented with an odd denominator. I'm very doubtful about the usefulness of such a function.

Comment: why not positive rationals with odd denominator?

Comment: Yeah, fixed comment

Comment: If you are okay with complex numbers, it can be extended to the entire domain $\Bbb C$ via $(-1)^x=e^{i\pi x}$.

Comment: This is a very good question ! I guess you want $x, f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ only, so as @egreg said you may have rationals with odd denominator only... I'm very interested in a proof of this, are you looking for $\mathcal{C}^0$ joints ?

Comment: @BusyAnt The function $e^{i\pi x}$ is real only when the real part of $x$ is an integer. If you enumerate all the branches of log you get $e^{(2n+1)i\pi x}$, so if you want $f(x),x$ to be real for some value of $n$ (which can depend on $x$) you get $(2n+1)x\in\Bbb Z$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$, so $x$ is a rational number with odd denominator.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Nice quick proof, now can we do something with the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to get a bigger domain for OP's function ? Or is it just wasted time ?

Comment: @BusyAnt No, the various branches of log that are used in "nearby" rational numbers are not compatible. This is probably why @${}$egreg thinks it is not a useful function. The "best" $(-1)^x$ lookalike IMO is $e^{i\pi x}$, which is analytic, holomorphic, continuous, etc., and defined on all of $\Bbb C$. It is real only at the integers, and this is as good as you will get if you want these properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem in defining such a function over the rational numbers that can be represented with an odd denominator. However such a function will not obey the standard rules for exponentials:
$$
(-1)^{1/3}=-1
$$
but, on the other hand,
$$
((-1)^{2/1})^{1/6}=1
$$

The usefulness of such a function is unclear.

However, you can define it as a *multivalued function* over the complex numbers, using the fact that $-1=e^{i\pi+2ki\pi}$ ($k$ any integer)
$$
(-1)^x=e^{(2k+1)ix\pi}
$$
Note that in general this will have infinitely many values, unless $x$ is rational. If $x$ is rational and $x=a/b$, with odd $b$, then only one of the values will be real and, conversely, if one of the values is real, then $x$ is rational and $x=a/b$ with odd $b$. (Exercise on complex numbers.)

Comment: The short answer is, the domain should be integer $x$ (because of the difficulties in defining a *function* $f(x)$ with larger domain pointed out by egreg).

Comment: For an explicit description of $f(x)$: for $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and $b$ odd, $(-1)^{a/b}$ is $-1$ if $a$ is odd and $1$ if it is even, so in fact $(-1)^{a/b}=(-1)^a$.